# Change iPhone file permissions wihout jailbreak

Tags: ssh, backup, iphone

I want to delete some apps (games) but backup their save game data.
Since there's no way to save your saved game data the only way to backup this files is using something like iFunBox and copy both Documents and Library folders to your PC.

The problem is restoring them. I've an iPhone 4S 6.1.3 and Win7 and when I install the app again and send both folders to iPhone using iFunBox, their permission is not 775 so I can't run the game.

Is there any workaround? I don't want to jailbreak my iPhone.
Thanks!

Comment: There is no other solution.  In order to change the permissions on those files you need to jailbreak your phone.

Comment: Innocent question: if I change this files permissions in a based unix OS and then send to iPhone will it keep the permissions?

Comment: You can try but its unlikely.